# Efficiently running rdist.earth() with large data sets

Tags: r

I am new to R and am currently using the rdist.earth() function in the fields package to compute distances between pairs of coordinates. My problem is that my data set is very large and it is almost impossible to run the function. I'm currently running the code below.

```
   distance.matrix <- round(5280 * rdist.earth(x, y, miles = TRUE))
```

The x dataframe has ~ 1040000 rows, and y has ~ 1200. 
I have to run this on a server for it to work, and it still takes a long time to compute. The returned distance matrix is about 8 gb, and almost impossible to work with.

Is there a way to vectorize rdist.earth(), or some other strategy so I can run this more efficiently?

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to vectorize the function:

`rdist.earth.vec` from the same `fields` package computes a vector of pairwise great circle distances between corresponding elements of the input locations.

I had a similar problem, although with not such a large amount of location pairs.

Here is what worked for me in a 2400*2400 location matrix.
I combined all locations into dyadic pairs in a dataframe (`?combn()`), then called `rdist.earth.vec`.

```
dyadic$GCD <- rdist.earth.vec(x1 =dyadic[,c("lon_orig","lat_orig")],
                              x2 =dyadic[,c("lon_dest","lat_dest")],
                              miles = FALSE)
```

The calculation for the 2.M+ rows was done in a blink of an eye.

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much you can do about not being able to work with the resulting matrix.  It's a giant dense matrix.  You can probably speed up the rdist.earth function by storing some results rather than recalculating and using tcrossprod:

```
library(fields)

rdist.earth2 <- function(x1, x2, miles = TRUE, R = NULL){
  if (is.null(R)) {
    if (miles) 
      R <- 3963.34
    else R <- 6378.388
  }
  x1 <- x1 / 180
  x2 <- x2 / 180
  x1cs <- cbind(cospi(x1), sinpi(x1))
  x2cs <- cbind(cospi(x2), sinpi(x2))
  pp <- tcrossprod(cbind(x1cs[,1] * x1cs[,2], x1cs[,2] * x1cs[,3], x1cs[,4]),
                   cbind(x2cs[,1] * x2cs[,2], x2cs[,2] * x2cs[,3], x2cs[,4]))
  pp <- pmin(pmax(-1, pp), 1)
  matrix(R * acos(pp), nrow = nrow(x1), ncol = nrow(x2))
}



rlat     <- function(n) runif(n, -90, 90)
rlong    <- function(n) runif(n, -180, 180)
rlatlong <- function(n) cbind(rlong(n), rlat(n))
x1 <- rlatlong(1000)
x2 <- rlatlong(1000)

system.time(ans1 <- rdist.earth(x1, x2))
system.time(ans2 <- rdist.earth2(x1, x2))
identical(all.equal(ans1, ans2), TRUE)
```

I'm getting about a 30% improvement in speed and it also seems a little more memory efficient.  You can also split it up and try to do it in parallel.

```
library(iterator)
library(foreach)
ans3 <- foreach(b = iter(x1, by = 'row', chunksize = 100000L ), .combine='rbind') %do% rdist.earth2(b, x2)
identical(all.equal(ans1, ans3), TRUE)
```

You would have to register a parallel backend and replace my %do% with %dopar%. This won't help much with speed but it might let you do it on your machine rather than a server depending on how much memory you have.  I can do a 1000000 * 1000 on my machine with 16 Gb of RAM.